# Modifying XLSX dataset using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to modify a semi-large (around 5k entries) dataset using pandas. Unfortunately, I've not been able to find a way to properly handle the data as the first column is used as a group identifier and has some empty cells, as follows:

```
Column1----------Column2-------------Column3
<br>USER1-------details on user1---------more details on user 1</br>
<br>N/A-----------details on user1---------more details on user 1</br>
<br>N/A-----------details on user1---------more details on user 1</br>
<br>N/A-----------details on user1---------more details on user 1</br>
<br>N/A-----------details on user1---------more details on user 1</br>
<br>USER2--------details on user2---------more details on user 2</br>
<br>N/A-----------details on user2---------more details on user 2</br>
<br>N/A-----------details on user2---------more details on user 2</br>
<br>N/A-----------details on user2---------more details on user 2</br>
<br>N/A-----------details on user2---------more details on user 2</br>
```

The way using df.groupby() in pandas is unfortunately not working in this case as it would not be able to assign the values properly.

One way would be to simply replace 'None' by the respective user-identifier in the initial dataset; however, that would make the dataset somewhat less readable (I pull the xlsx from Google Spreadsheets, modify it with pandas and then re-publish it to Google Spreadsheets, so that I can work with it there).

My (optimal) workflow would be as follows: 1. Get a dataset with the structure as explained above. 2. Merge a second dataset with the dataset from 1 (using user-credentials from column 1 as a index).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the dataframe into pandas, you can duplicate `Column1`:

```
df['column1_v2'] = df.column1
```

Then you can `pad` `column1_v2` so that you can use it in your merge:

```
df.column1_v2 = df.column1_v2.fillna(method='pad')
df = pd.merge(df, df2, how='left', on='column1_v2')
```

Finally, before bringing this back to `xlxs` and Google Sheets, you can just delete the column you created for the merge:

```
df = df.drop('column1_v2', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. Performance should be good for 5k entries.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'column1' : ['User1', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
                                 'User2', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                    'column2' : ['details user 1(1)','details user 1(2)',
                                 'details user 1(3)','details user 1(4)',
                                 'details user 2(1)','details user 2(2)',
                                 'details user 2(3)','details user 2(4)'],
                     'column3' : ['more details user 1(1)','more details user 1(2)',
                                 'more details user 1(3)','more details user 1(4)',
                                 'more details user 2(1)','more details user 2(3)',
                                 'more details user 2(3)','more details user 2(4)']})

print(df1)
#  column1            column2                 column3
#0   User1  details user 1(1)  more details user 1(1)
#1     NaN  details user 1(2)  more details user 1(2)
#2     NaN  details user 1(3)  more details user 1(3)
#3     NaN  details user 1(4)  more details user 1(4)
#4   User2  details user 2(1)  more details user 2(1)
#5     NaN  details user 2(2)  more details user 2(3)
#6     NaN  details user 2(3)  more details user 2(3)
#7     NaN  details user 2(4)  more details user 2(4)

def rename_column1(df1):
    list1 = []
    temp = []

    for r in zip(df1['column1']):
        if r[0] is not np.nan:
            list1.append(r[0])
            temp = r[0]
        if r[0] is np.nan:
            list1.append(temp)

    df1['column1'] = list1
    return df1

rename_column1(df1)

print(df1)
#  column1            column2                 column3
#0   User1  details user 1(1)  more details user 1(1)
#1   User1  details user 1(2)  more details user 1(2)
#2   User1  details user 1(3)  more details user 1(3)
#3   User1  details user 1(4)  more details user 1(4)
#4   User2  details user 2(1)  more details user 2(1)
#5   User2  details user 2(2)  more details user 2(3)
#6   User2  details user 2(3)  more details user 2(3)
#7   User2  details user 2(4)  more details user 2(4)


df1 = df1.groupby(['column1'], as_index = False, sort = False).agg(', '.join)

print(df1)
#      column1  column2                                             column3
#    0   User1  details user 1(1), details user 1(2), details ...   more details user 1(1), more details user 1(2)...  
#    1   User2  details user 2(1), details user 2(2), details ...   more details user 2(1), more details user 2(3)... 

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['User1','User2'],
                    'new_c2' : [0,0],
                    'new_c3' : [0,0]})

print(df2)
#  column1  new_c2  new_c3
#0   User1       0       0
#1   User2       0       0

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'column1', how = 'left')

print(df3)

#      column1  column2                                             column3                                             new_c2  new_c3 
#    0   User1  details user 1(1), details user 1(2), details ...   more details user #1(1), more details user 1(2)...       0       0 
#    1   User2  details user 2(1), details user 2(2), details ...   more details user #2(1), more details user 2(3)...       0       0
```